# JSON vs RubyValidations. How to define an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I try to catch a validation message with a `$.parseJSON(xhr.responseText).errors` but an allert message hows me "undefined"  and I dont understand why.

hier are my validations:

```
validates :upload_file_name,  :presence   => true,
                                :format     =>{:with => %r{\.(jpg)$}i,:message =>"It should be a pdf File"}

  validates_uniqueness_of :upload_file_name, :message => "blabla"

  validates :upload_file_size,  :inclusion  => {:in =>1.megabytes..20.megabytes,:message=>"bla"}
```

json:

```
format.json{ render json: {error: @upload.errors.full_messages}, :status =>422}
```

and javascript for that:

```
 $('#fileupload').fileupload({       


        error: function(xhr){
          var errors = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText).errors
          alert(errors)         
        }
              });
```

Comment: Isn't it a type in your json, try 'error' instead of 'errors' because when you render the json you are passing just 'error'

Comment: post it as an aswer and I will vote it up=))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistype in you controller, change it to the following that it should work

```
format.json{ render json: {errors: @upload.errors.full_messages}, :status =>422}
```